# ObjectPool with external Instance Creation

Tags: c++, templates, object

I try to modify an existing object pool class so that I am able to pass an instance creator class as an argument to the object pool. Basically I want to be able to keep the actual object construction out of the memory pool so I have more freedom in what way I create instances to be pooled.

Here is the object pool definition:

```
template < 
    typename T, 
    typename InstanceCreator = DefaultInstanceFactory<T>
>
class ObjectPool : private noncopyable {
...
}
```

So I would create an ObjectPool like this

```
ObjectPool<int> intPool((DefaultInstanceFactory<int>()));
```

or

```
ObjectPool<IntClass, IntClass::InstanceFactory> intPool (IntClass::InstanceFactory (1));
```

The default Instance creator looks like this

```
template <typename T>
class DefaultInstanceFactory {
public:
    T * operator ()() const {
        return new T;
    }
};
```

Inside that ObjectPool class is a nested class that stores the items

```
class PooledItem {
public:
    char data[OBJECT_SIZE];
    PooledItem * next;
    bool initialized;

    PooledItem() 
    : initialized(false) {}

    ~PooledItem() { 
        // --- call T destructor
        if (initialized) 
            cast()->~T(); 
    }
    T * cast() { 
        return reinterpret_cast<T *>(data); 
    };
};
```

There is a borrowObject method to acquire an object and here is my actual problem:

```
T * borrowObject() {
    PooledItem * item = getItem();
    T * obj = item->cast();
    if (! item->initialized) {
        // old original line, call the defaut constructor of T
        new (obj) T();
        // how to integrate the external Instance Creator at this point?
        //new (instCreator_ ()) T(1);
        //instCreator_ ();
        item->initialized = true;
    }

    if (obj == NULL) {
        throw ObjectPoolException(
            "Object is NULL!", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
    }

    return obj;
}
```

In above method I marked the actual problem lines. I have no idea how to replace the placement new `new (obj) T()` line with the external Instance creator, to just reuse that memory.

For completeness, the method for returning an object to the pool looks like this

```
void returnObject(T * obj) {
    // --- Get containing PooledItem pointer
    PooledItem * item = reinterpret_cast<PooledItem *>(obj);
    // --- Make sure object came from this pool
    if (item->next != reinterpret_cast<PooledItem *>(this)) {
        // throw Exception
    }

    // --- Destroy object now if we want to reconstruct it later
    if (destroyOnRelease) {
        item->cast()->~T();
        item->initialized = false;
    }
```

Could anybody give me some help how to modify the methods so that the external Instance Creator gets integrated properly? I do not know up to now, if I need to change something in the returnObject method, up to now I think not.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to change InstanceFactory's signature to take a pointer

```
template <typename T>
class DefaultInstanceFactory {
public:
  void operator ()(T* out) const {
      return new(out) T;
  }
};
```